# Provisioning fields and content types through JSOM

Tags: client-object-model

Im trying to add a field to a content type through some code on Chris o' Briens blog [here](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/06/sp2013-host-web-apps-provisioning.html). I have modified the code slightly to add multiple fields to a content type. See below:

```
    function SetupServiceCatalog()
{
    LinkFieldToContentType("Contacts");
    LinkFieldToContentType("Confidentiality");
}
function LinkFieldToContentType(fieldName) {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    var web = clientContext.get_web();
    // Retrieve all content types
    ContentTypeCollection = web.get_contentTypes();
    // Retrieve the previously created field
    field = web.get_fields().getByTitle(fieldName);
 
    clientContext.load(ContentTypeCollection);
    clientContext.load(field);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySuccess, onCreationFail);
}
 
function onQuerySuccess() {
    var contentTypeEnumerator = ContentTypeCollection.getEnumerator();
    var myCt;
    // Find the previously created content type
    while (contentTypeEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var ct = contentTypeEnumerator.get_current();
        if (ct.get_name() === "OSD Wiki Template") {
            myCt = ct;
            break;
        }
    }
 
    if (myCt != null) {
        // Create a field link reference
        var fieldLink = new SP.FieldLinkCreationInformation();
        fieldLink.set_field(field);
        // Add the field link reference to the content type
        myCt.get_fieldLinks().add(fieldLink);
        myCt.update(true);
        
        var clientContext1 = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

        clientContext1.load(myCt);
        clientContext1.executeQueryAsync(onCreationSuccess1, onCreationFail1);
    }
}
function onCreationFail() {
}

function onCreationSuccess1() {
}
function onCreationFail1(sender, args) {
}
```

However the final issue i'm experiencing is the clientContext1.executeQueryAsync which keeps going to the failure callback with the error of "Unknown Error". I'm not sure if its because I have a executeQueryAsync within a onQuerySuccess or? But i have a feeling its the way I'm calling this method twice, the second time within the first calls OnQuerySuccess.

Can anyone suggest what may be wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Came on this old post with no good answer so decided to add my solution:

```
var currSite = "/";
var ctId = "0x01002F31FB62E029B146B5D9CF65E832561B";//you should get this yourself, see below
var fldInternalName = "Confidentiality";

var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(currSite);
var web = ctx.get_web();
var fld = web.get_fields().getByInternalNameOrTitle(fldInternalName);

var contentTypeCollection = web.get_contentTypes(); 
var ct = contentTypeCollection.getById(ctId);

var fieldRef = new SP.FieldLinkCreationInformation();
fieldRef.set_field(fld);

ct.get_fieldLinks().add(fieldRef);
ct.update(true);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(onCreationSuccess1, onCreationFail1);
```

My call to get the contenttypeid (ctId). It is based on REST as this is our preferred approach.

```
var ctName = "Contacts";    
$.ajax({
        url: currSite+"_api/web/AvailableContentTypes?$select=Name,Id,StringId&$filter=Name eq '" + ctName + "'",
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
        }
    });
```